# No language defined for the project: Ada GNAT GPS

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I've been having this issue where I've installed the GNAT (x86 windows 2017) on my other machine, and I suddenly have these errors, `Error: no native compiler found for language 'ada', default runtime` and `no languages defined for this project`. All of this is under the `.gpr` file of my project. This never happened to me on the other PC.

Comment: Try two things:  Make sure GNAT is in your PATH variable.  Also ensure you installed the correct version of GNAT. There are two for windows...one that compiles Windows programs and one that cross compiles to ARM.  You need the correct one for your project.

Comment: you can also try running gprconfig; it will at least tell you which GNATs are installed. Please also provide exact details in your question; what is the minimal gprfile and project? What does `which gcc` give you? Which command are you running to get that error?